# Uploading files directly on github.com

Tags: file-upload, github

can i upload my files to my github.com repository without using Github for Windows?
Is there any file upload button in github.com?

I searched through all the questions about file-upload on github but all have answers using github windows client.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to upload a file from `github.com`. However, you can create new files:

[image]

Comment: yeah i know creating files is an option but i wanted to upload my project files directly. but now i guess there is no way to do so.